# Main method in one class cannot use any objects in the same project Java

Tags: java

I have a class with the sole purpose of containing the main method. This main method calls to create an instance of my Reader1 object. However, the error my terminal returns is that it cannot find the Reader1 symbol. I tried another to instantiate another class in the same project but got the same error. I suspect I'm doing something wrong when setting up my project.

This is what my project looks like in eclipse:

[image]

Below is the code for Rectangle1.java and Reader1.java, respectively. Is there something I am missing that doesn't make Reader1 visible to Rectangle1? I figured if it is in the same folder, and public, then all other files in the same folder should be able to access it and create instances of it.

Rectangle1.java:

```
 /**
 * 
 * @author Ryan Kaviani, Jared Joo
 * @version 09/16/21
 */
public class Rectangle1 {
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Reader1 read = new Reader1(args[0]);
        read.executeRead();
        SkipList<String, Rectangle> a = new SkipList<String, Rectangle>();
    }
    
    //Compare using string compare
    
    //Insert {name}
    
    //Remove {name}
    
    //Remove 

}
```

Reader1.java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Reader1 {

    private SkipList<String, Rectangle> list;
    private String file;
    
    public Reader1(String file) {
        this.file = file;
        list = new SkipList<String, Rectangle>();
    }
    
    public void executeRead() {
        try {
            
            File testFile = new File(file);
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(testFile);
            
            while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scan.nextLine();
                //Splits the string using the delimiter of any amount of white spaces.
                String[] arr = line.split("\s+");
                int len = arr.length;
                
                if(arr[0].equals("insert")) {
                    System.out.println("Insert command");
                    /*if(list.insert(new Rectangle(name, x, y, w, h))) {
                        //basic output
                    }
                    else {
                        //failed output
                    }*/
                }               
                
                else if(arr[0].equals("remove")) {
                    if(len == 5) {  //coords
                        System.out.println("Remove coords command");
                    }
                    else {          //name
                        System.out.println("Remove name command");
                    }
                }
                
                else if(arr[0].equals("regionsearch")) {
                    System.out.println("RegionSearch command");
                }
                
                else if(arr[0].equals("intersections")) {
                    System.out.println("Intersections command");
                }
                
                else if(arr[0].equals("search")) {
                    System.out.println("Search command");
                }
                
                else if(arr[0].equals("dump")) {
                    System.out.println("Dump command");
                }
                
                else {
                    System.out.println("Unkown command");
                }
                
                //Write out command grabbers in main()
                //Write out the methods that will print every argument
                for(String x: arr) {
                    // Process the commands. First argument
                    // is our command, second and the rest 
                    // are command args.
                    
                    // Check if it's remove
                        // Check if arr has 5 elems, or 2
                            // Call Remove {x} {y} {w} {h} with next 4
                }
            }
            scan.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Ensure that the third class Rectangle has no errors. Do a clean build.

Comment: @JoopEggen SkipList has the same issue, though, and it has no errors. It still says cannot find symbol. Fixed up Rectangle so it has no errors. Same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The IDE turned out to be the issue. I was building on the terminal because I couldn't get the eclipse terminal to work, but I think the problem was that it skips out on some smaller operations that eclipse does.

The fix is to set up a run configuration from within eclipse (if you want to enter arguments). Otherwise just run it from within eclipse.